# Elementary properties of modular addition and multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, congruences

> Prove: For every natural number $m$,
>
> 1. $(Z_m , +_m)$ is an algebraic system that is associative and commutative with identity element $[0]$. Every element has an inverse.
> 2. $(Z_m , ._m)$ is an algebraic system is associative and commutative. If $m>1$, the system has identity element $[1]$.

I'm new to this topic so my understanding is pretty low plus I don't really understand congruent classes all that well.

Comment: what is an "*algebraic system*"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure

Comment: Why is this off-topic?

Comment: I didn't give the *close vote*. I gave the answer and later saw that it was marked as *"off-topic"*.

Comment: But I don't understand how was it voted off-topic.

Comment: This has been closed as off-topic because you have not shown us any attempts you have made to solve it. Before doing this problem you should work on understanding congruent classes. Once you do that, then try to prove each property at a time. If you are still stuck, tell us which properties you have been able to prove and which not. In other words, show us you have been doing some of your own work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define a relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ as follows: $a \sim b$ if an only if $m|(a-b).$ I can be checked that $\sim$ is actually an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{Z}.$ Let's denote the equivalence class of $a$ by $[a].$ Let $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is the collection of all equivalence classes. For $[a], [b] \in \mathbb{Z},$ define $[a] +_m [b] := [a+b]$ where $a+b$ is the usual addition in $\mathbb{Z}.$ First we need to show that it is well defined, i.e. if $[a] = [a'], [b] = [b']$ then $[a]+_m[b] = [a']+_m[b'].$ In other words, we need to show that  $[a+b] = [a' + b'].$ But this happen precisely when $m|(a+b -a' -b').$ Now $[a] = [a'] \Rightarrow m|(a-a'), [b] = [b'] \Rightarrow m|(b - b') \Rightarrow m|(a+b -a'-b').$ This show that the operation $+_m$ defined on $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is well defined.

To prove that it is associative, we need to show that $([a] +_m [b]) +_m [c] = [a] +_m ([b] +_m [c]).$ Note that $([a] +_m [b]) +_m [c] = [a+b] +_m [c] = [(a+b) + c]$ and $[a] +_m [(b] +_m [c]) = [a] +_m [b+c] = [a+(b+c)].$ Since $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z},$ we have $(a+b)+c = a+ (b+c).$ Hence we have the associativity. Similarly, we will have the commutativity.

$[0]$ is an identity element, because $[a]+_m[0] = [a +0] = [a] = [0+a] = [0] +_m [a].$

In a similar way, you can prove for $(\mathbb{Z}_m, \cdot_m).$ Here the operation is defined by $[a] \cdot_m[b] = [ab],$ where $ab$ stands for the standard multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}.$ I hope this will help.